# Why do WebApi routing config defaults not include the action param?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am a bit new to WebApi so maybe someone can explain this to me, the default route added for WebApis is:

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

So given an ApiController that looks like this:

```
public class LookupController : ApiController
{

    [HttpGet] 
    public IHttpActionResult GetCountries()
    { 
        // do stuff
        return Ok();
    }

    [HttpGet] 
    public IHttpActionResult GetStates()
    { 
        // do stuff
        return Ok();
    }

}
```

How would it know which action to call? It wouldn't right?

Shouldn't the default Route be more like:

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ApiWithAction",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Or should you only have one GET/UPDATE/DELETE etc per ApiController? Which really wouldn't cater for some scenarios...

Comment: The default route lets you have actions that are defined by their names. For example `Get` would be an HTTP GET, `Put` would be an HTTP PUT etc.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking your controller should never look like that. Out of the box the idea is that a controller handles requests for a single entity (e.g. Customer) and the operations, which map to HTTP verbs, operate against that entity. So under normal circumstances your controller would look something like the following (created using scaffolding against a simple model class, method bodies omitted for brevity):

```
public class CustomerController : ApiController
{
    public IQueryable<Customer> GetCustomers()
    {
    }

    [ResponseType(typeof(Customer))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetCustomer(int id)
    {
    }

    [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    public IHttpActionResult PutCustomer(int id, Customer customer)
    {
    }

    [ResponseType(typeof(Customer))]
    public IHttpActionResult PostCustomer(Customer customer)
    {
    }

    [ResponseType(typeof(Customer))]
    public IHttpActionResult DeleteCustomer(int id)
    {
    }
}
```

If you have more business-oriented operations to perform (e.g. BillCustomer), rather than just the basic CRUD operations, I would suggest creating a separate route for those. We did that in one of our applications and it created a nice logical separation. For example:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "RestApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "RpcApi",
    routeTemplate: "rpc/{controller}/{action}"
);
```

Comment: The problem I see with this is when you have multiple actions relating to the same entity, which don't make much sense to split into seperate controllers. I guess two get methods might work but again the routing wouldn't apply, what is recommended?

Comment: In that case you would get an error saying `Multiple actions were found that match the request` which is when you need to set up different routing.

Comment: @shenku, I'm not sure I understand your comment. If the multiple actions relate to the same entity then they would be in the same controller, not separate controllers. As the example I posted shows, you have several actions relating to the Customer entity and they are all in the same controller.

Comment: @CraigW. I think what he is saying is, for example you have 2 actions like `public List<Customers> GetCustomers()` and `public List<Customer> GetDeadCustomers()` then how would it work. My comment to that was saying that it won't without further routing changes.

Comment: @DavidG you are correct that is eactly what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Web API figures out which method to call based on routing data. You don't need to specify the action because Web API will use the **verb(GET, POST,DELETE,etc)** of the request.

If you would like to have multiple GET actions in a controller, you can specify a route for each action.

```
[Route("api/lookup/countries"]
[HttpGet] 
    public IHttpActionResult GetCountries()
    { 
        // do stuff
        return Ok();
    }

[Route("api/lookup/states"]
    [HttpGet] 
    public IHttpActionResult GetStates()
    { 
        // do stuff
        return Ok();
    }
```

More information is available here http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: You don't strictly need to have a route for every action, you can add in another route that allows you to specify the action name as @shenku put in his question.